# Bittorent protocol. Multiple downloads between same peers

Tags: sockets, protocols, p2p, bittorrent, handshake

I'am just started to studying bittorent protocol and have one question about bittorrent clients that uses same ports for all incoming connections.

Here is example of my problem:

**1st connection:** A local peer listening on **1.0.0.1:1** and receives connection from remote peer with address **2.0.0.2:2**. **OK. Start PWP**

**2nd connection:** A local peer listening on **1.0.0.1:1** and receives connection from remote peer with address **3.0.0.3:2**. **OK. Start PWP**

**3rd connection:** A local peer listening on **1.0.0.1:1** and receives connection from remote peer with address **2.0.0.2:2** but with another InfoHash. **???**

Is **3rd connection** possible or remote peer(**2.0.0.2:2**) have to track it's connections to local peer(**1.0.0.1:1**) and will connect to local peer through different port and also announce himself 2nd time to tracker with different port or/and peer id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for two peers to use more than one connection, sharing torrents with different *InfoHashes* at the same time. There are two different cases depending on what type of transport protocol the connection is done over.

#### TCP connection

When a bittorrent peer shares over TCP, it opens up a incoming port that is announced to the tracker(s) and that port is the one used to connect to by every other peer that initiates a connection to that peer. However, a peer that initiates and makes a outgoing connections uses a different port number for every outgoing connection.
That makes it possible to uniquely identify every connection by its *(IP:PORT<->IP:PORT)*-pair.

#### uTP/UDP connection

When a peer shares over uTP/UDP it uses the same port for both incoming and outgoing connections. To make it possible to differentiate between the connections, [the uTP protocol extension](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0029.html) instead uses a `connection_id` that is unique for every connection.
The advantage with using the same port for both incoming and outgoing connections is that it makes [UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) possible.

---

The peer makes a separate announce to the tracker(s) for every different *InfoHash*.
All modern clients reuses the same incoming port for all torrents it shares.

Comment: "a peer that initiates and makes a outgoing connections **uses a different port number for every outgoing connection**." This fact was unknown for me. Now all is clear. Thanks!